# Asked for a Increase response was "I'll think about it", Should I take this as a No?

Tags: raise, position

As the title mentions. I have recently threw some various considerations decided to ask my boss for a increase on my salary. In essence my boss's response was that "He will think about it".
Shall I take this as a no and leave it be? or should I approach him again, and if so how much time should I give it and how do I go about it?

To shorten a long story. I am junior who is doing senior work and I provide a exclusive service for the company. I have not gotten any increase since I started here, thus felt it was possibly time.

Note: Deleted old question to shorten and stay on topic and avoid a rant. Hope this is more clear

Edit: Thanks for all the Responses, Apologies if there isn't to much clarity I dint want to head into a rant as that is what it would turn into, This is however tho my first time ever asking for a increase so I had no idea how to approach it.

Comment: Do you think there is a time frame where it goes from He hasn't decided to I think its a no but he doesn't want to directly tell me, as in if it were 2 months from now and still have yet to hear anything.

Comment: Nobody likes to be put on the spot. Asking your boss to accept your demands immediately isn't reasonable. Every decision has to be thought through.

Comment: @Polygnome This is very true. I wasn't sure of the procedure as this is the first time im ever asking. I guess i Expected a no or yes on the spot

Comment: _"I am junior who is doing senior work and I provide a exclusive service for the company."_ Does your boss perceive it the same way or did you mention that when asking for a raise?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere how many years should the op wait for a response the boss doesn’t want to give?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tactially mistake on your part.

"I'll think about it" is a perfectly valid answer, but it can mean two things:

1. Your boss needs to do some actual homework and thinking
2. Your boss has no intention of doing anything and just ignores you hoping it'll go away by itself.

You should have clarified what exactly that means and what the time frame is. A good answer would have been

> Great, thank you. When can we reconnect on this? What can I do in the
> mean time to help and drive this along ?

This A) pushes for a a specific deadline of the "thinking" and B) signals that you are not going to go away peacefully.

If your boss's answer is still evasive (I don't kow yet, hard to tell, we are kind of busy at the moment), there is good chance the answer is either "no" or it won't happen in the forseeable future. If you get something like "Let's talk at our next 1:1 in two weeks" you are in your way for a potential raise.

**EDIT**
If you get no replies within a two weeks, ask again. This time be prepared :

1. If they still want more time, ask how much, what the time specfically is needed for and how you or someone else can help with that.
2. If they are evasive, ask for specific criteria & rules for a raise, so you can help with assessing yourself against the criteria and work towards them.
3. If the answer is "no" or "not now". Ask why and what you need to do to make it a yes. Are they looking for a change in certain behaviors, more or different skills, quality or timeliness of deliverables? Make sure it's specific and measurable and not just "I know it when I see it".

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably avoid asking for a deadline up front. Maybe give it a couple of weeks.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I usually agree with your views, but on this one, I beg to differ. With no deadline, in no time, those weeks will turn into months and quarters and years. Asking for a deadline is not offensive, it shows that you're willing to conclude.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like OP missed the opportunity. Can't they simply assume (1) and bring it upon a few days later?

Comment: Issue was He barely gave me chance to speak, I had this whole speach planned out how I would sell it, I dint even get to finish it. I was interrupted with Covid has made finances difficult, Which for the company it really hasn't If anything we make more right now. He said he would think about it and if i remember correctly i was super stressed its foggy but I remember him saying this opens the discussion for us or something like that? does that means he expects a follow up

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have already asked, I wont go though how to ask for a raise etc... and I will assume your company doesn't have a specific policy on how promotions or raises work.

Responses are probably going to be very opinion based on this, it depends on your relationship with your boss regarding how pushy you can be. I would not take it as a No. There is genuinely a lot to think about and confirm before making a decision, eg:

- Do you deserve it
- Can they afford it
- How valuable are you
- What is a fair price
- What is the least they can give you, that keeps you happy
- Will other staff ask for raises too, if they find out
- Would that money be better spent on hiring an additional person

IE. There are a few things to think about, and if you have more than 1 boss, they will both need to agree.

Personally, I would give them 1 month, and then follow up. I would do this 2 times (so you have asked 3 times in total). You want a yes or no answer.

If you only get excuses like "we're thinking about it", "it's complicated" etc... then I'd assume it's a No, and the boss wants to keep stringing you along.

Comment: So see the "Boss" is actually my CEO I asked, We are a small company maybe 25 people. The response from him was that Covid has finances difficult I sadly know that this isnt the case as I alone bring in enough to cover our entire department x2 over. 

Well I think i Deserve it because long story short no1 here can develop mobile apps. He asked me to make one and said "If you finish it you can get a increase" I did finish it but it never launched because of covid(Its a trade show app)  The previous guy in my position had to be baby sit so I think I hold value, The price is still less then the

Comment: Initial offering price In. So I earn 14k (Not dollars) The job post was 15-20k Thus I thought it would be fair to ask for something like 18k As its still less then the max and I have 1 year here now. No other members will ask they are to scared to ask. The money wouldnt be able to hire someone els. In essence To hire someone with the same skill level as me theyd need someone with a bachelors and that person wont take less then 25k. So based on that what do u think? Was i Qualified for that increase

Comment: @Someone Based on what you've said, it sounds like they have no intention of giving you a raise. And as you're making less than the salary range initially advertised and you've been there a year, sorry, but I think that's unacceptable! Unless the company is struggling financially. If not, then I would start looking at other jobs.

Comment: @Someone This sounds a lot like a company I worked for as a junior. They paid me just under the salary range. As I progressed and reached senior I was given more responsibility, but they always had some excuse not to give a pay rise. They never said no, but gave excuses like, "we don't know how Brexit will effect us", "we'll do it next month", next month comes: "it's too late now, we'll do it next year".... etc.  I made good friends with some of the HR staff, and later heard, the bosses weren't afraid I'd leave, so they wouldn't give me a pay rise. - I ended up leaving for a 60% pay rise.

Comment: @Someone I basically let that company string me along for 4-5 years. I was too comfortable and scared of leaving... and it set me back years financially.

Comment: Soz for only replying now been hectic honesty the only reason I took this job is because I was in the old dev catch 22 of need Exp but no company wants to give it to u so I took it for that reason I believe at this point there is no increase waiting for me now Weather I should ask about weather hes thought about it I dont know, But I do think ill be looking around next year in jan for a new position

Answer (score 1):

You can take it as a maybe, but more likely a "no".

Pick up a book on sales that focuses on closing strategies.  You left the door open for your boss, and he walked out, and you missed the sale.

When you negotiate, you need to close the sale before the meeting is over, or it's always "no".

Absolutely follow up in about two weeks, set up a meeting, and be prepared with closing tactics to overcome objections.  Here are some examples

https://blog.close.com/sales-objection-handling/

Everything is sales.  In the future, be prepared to be able to secure a comittment, if there are things beyond your control such as "Well, I'll need to get approval from higher ups", follow up with, "Great, when will you know".  Then check in with him on that date.

Also, float your resume, get an idea of what you are worth, and if you can get some job offers, all the better.  You want to negotiate from a position of strength, going in knowing that even in the worst case scenario, you will have a job somewhere else waiting for you.  But, **DO NOT MENTION ANY OFFERS**  The point is to be able to move if you need to.

Don't be a lamb, be a lion.

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely a "no".  If it wasn't a "no", your boss would have given you some action items that you or he could do to forward your request to get that raise you want.  Something like, "I'll ask upper management if we have the budget", or "I'll keep this in mind for our manager standup next week" or "An increase in salary would require an official promotion and you are missing X, Y, Z to getting a promotion".  Those are action items, or actual reasons, why you can't get that raise right now and what you and/or he can do to get you that raise you want.

"I'll think about it" is a weasel way of saying "not now, and also not ever, and also I'm taking responsibility for gatekeeping you from this, and also don't ask me again".  It is most definitely a "no".  If you'd like to take the advice of one of the other answers, you can take the infinitesimally small chance that I am wrong and follow up with your boss around 1 week after you made the initial request (or thereafter), ask him if he's given it any thought, and what steps he is taking, or what steps you can take, to move that request along faster.  However, any inclination that he has not actually taken your request seriously (this is the vastly most likely response) should be taken as a "no, and also never raise this subject again", and you can do with that as you will.

Answer (score -4):

1. Unfortunately, sadly it's a case of "Duh".  It means No.
2. The one and only way to get a raise is: to be prepared to leave if you do not get a raise. Employees have no other leverage.
3. In your specific situation. It's an absolute basic of software that you **only move ahead from a first junior role by changing to a new job**. Would urge you to do this ASAP.

A footnote on 3, opinions differ, but I'd say most think you certainly **shouldn't stay at that first job too long**.  If you're a good programmer, it can't possibly take more than a whole year to move along to a "not a starter job" job.

Life is very short. And for programmers, as with say running backs in US Football, life is very, very, very short.

Comment: That's a lot of "facts" without any kind of evidence to back it up... especially considering other answers are a bit more nuanced on how OP should treat this situation.

Comment: This answer doesn't quantify anything or state why a year is the magic number to move on from your first job.